# Security of (2,2) Shamir's visual secret sharing scheme : How are the 2 shares random?

Tags: secret-sharing, randomness, visual-cryptography

From the [Visual Cryptography](http://www.fe.infn.it/u/filimanto/scienza/webkrypto/visualdecryption.pdf) by Shamir and Noar.

Let us take the pixel expansion as 2. Therefore, each pixel will be represented by 2 pixels (also called as subpixels) in a share. Since this is a (2,2) scheme, we will have 2 shares. In order to create share1 for a white pixel, a fair coin is tossed with 2 possibilities of subpixels - Black&White or White&Black - either one of these 2 choices is chosen to represent a white pixel. It is clear that Share1 is random.

In order to create share2 for a white pixel, is a coin tossed again? 
If yes, then how is reconstruction of a white pixel assured?
If no, then how is share2 random?
Assuming that in the reconstructed image, the white pixel will be 50% black and 50% white.

Comment: The example describing the scenario is on slide number 7 on this ppt https://www.slideshare.net/pallavikhandekar212/visual-cryptography-15843873

Comment: First of all, you can delete your comments. Could you tell me where in the article? There is not coin tossing in the article.

Comment: @kelalaka The scheme is well explained with the help of coin tossing here. https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~dstinson/visual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, coin tossing represents a uniform random generator. Therefore, the selections are assumed to be uniform.

In order to create a share for a pixel, as you mentioned, a pixel split into two subpixels. A share for

- a white pixel can be $[(B|W),(B|W)]$ or $[(W|B),(W|B)]$
- a black pixel can be $[(B|W),(W|B)]$ or $[(W|B),(B|W)]$, where in $[(x,y)]$, $x$ represents the color of left pixel and $y$ represents the color of right pixel.

or, one can see from the image;

[image: From https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~dstinson/visual.html]

The superposition is putting the images on top of each other. White shares construct a half white and half black square and black shares construct a black square. When the selection is random, the shares are indistinguishable from being white or black.

**How a share is constructed**

For each pixel, toss a coin to select a row. For example, assuming that when the toss result is Tail, we select the first rows;

- for white pixels, select $[(B|W),(B|W)]$ and
- for black pixels, select $[(B|W),(W|B)]$.

Similarly, for Head result, we select the second rows.

- for white pixels, select $[(W|B),(W|B)]$ and
- for black pixels, select $[(W|B),(B|W)]$.

**The confusion**

If we toss a coin for the second share (instead of selecting the share together), then for example; for a white pixel after a Tail (select first row $(B|W)$), we may select the second row with a Head then the white pixel will be shared as $(B|W)$ and $(W|B)$. In superposition, however, this constructs a black pixel $(B,B)$. Therefore, they must be selected together.

Share 1 and share 2 are random in group-wise.